# Python infinite __call__ attribute

Tags: python, attributes

I have this simple function:

```
def f():
    print("heh")
```

When I am calling f in reality I am calling its call method. But when I am calling a call method of f in reality I a calling a call method of call method of f. And so on and so on.

How does far does python go when call f(), it clearly must stop somewhere?

I was wondering whether this can go to infinity and it turns out that 100 000 is enough to crash Python.

```
>>> exec('f'+100000*'.__call__'+'()')

========= RESTART ==========
```

What's the reason of this crash?

Comment: *"when I am calling a call method of f in reality I a calling a call method of call method of f. And so on and so on"* - this assumption is clearly incorrect, as Python programs (sometimes) work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 'call' on an object causes the interpreter to look for a way to call it. When that is resolved by locating a `__call__` method, that method is invoked, and then something real happens. The `__call__` method can't just invoke the same mechanism on itself.

In the case of a function object, I believe there is an internal method table which is directly consulted first to see if there's a defined (C language) call handler, and that is invoked. There may also be a `__call__` attribute which does the same thing, but I think the engine checks the table first (some of this may have been reworked in Py 3).

The 'C' langauge call handler for functions is handed a reference to the function object, and a package of parameters. The function object contains a reference to a code object, and another to the proper global namespace. The code object contains a description of what parameters are expected, and all the information needed to actually set up the call on the python stack.

When you call a method of a class, there's a little binder object with its own call method (containing a pointer to the 'self' and to the actual method').

I guess the main point is that some objects have `__call__` methods coded in Python, but for many types the interpreter can go straight to C code after looking in the object's internal type descriptor. Another example is calling a type object , such as str, where the C-language constructor will be invoked.

Comment: Thanks, thats reasonable. And why does it crash python? exec('f'+100000*'.__call__'+'()')

Comment: Probably because in this case you are creating 100000 nested recursions in the C stack, while doing all the 'get attributes'. I.e. it happens before the interpeter can reach the call. It may even be happening in the compiler.

Comment: Yes. Try this:  `compile('f' + '.__call__'*100000 + '()','dummy_name','single')`

Comment: Whereas you can do this: `t=f`  `for i in range(100000): t = t.__call__`   `t()`   So it's the compiler that crashes.